# A function that's $f(x)=0$ for every finite $x$, but $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

This arise from a physically realized question: suppose a finite number, say $1$, was eventually distributed over a finite interval, i.e. $[-N/2,N/2]$. As $N$ became the entire real axis, $f(x)=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{N}=0$ for any finite $x$. However, there was a supposed "conservation law" that must hold, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)=1$.

Thus a function that $f(x)=0$ for every finite $x$, but $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)=1$ was required.

I tried to implement $f(x)=\delta(1/N)$. However, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\delta(x)=0$, and $\infty$ was not exactly a defined element.

Another attempt was to include $\omega$ into the integration, i.e. $\int_{x\in \{ \omega \}\cup \mathbb{R} } \delta(x-\omega) dx$, it worked but the set was nolonger real, and it became somewhat ambiguous.

I also thought of using complex number and use residual theorem. But since the real axis was all $0$, it became $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

How to define a function that's $f(x)=0$ for every finite $x$, but $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)=1$?

Comment: What do you mean by "finite" in this context?

Comment: No such function.

Comment: @Reveillark suppose $x$ was an element, since it's a normed space. $||x||<m$ for some $m\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Would I be right in saying that you are searching for an object that preserves "uniform selection" on a set of infinite measure? You proposed to drag the $N$ to infinity for this reason, hoping to get a meaningful function, but got something absurd in the process, is that right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes. It's a proposed "understanding" of charges over a conductor. Both $0$ charge density and conservation of charge i.e. integrate to $1$ must simultaneously hold true.    ($\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N}$ wasn't exactly a number, but a description of the process. of course, those were "idea", but a proper mathematical definition should be possible. )

Comment: I see. Certainly the way you propose to do it does not hold water. Essentially : you want a non-trivial charge distribution, so that the density at each point is zero. This certainly cannot happen at *every* point. I think we require a higher mathematical structure to capture this. I am not aware of any such. However, in the context of "uniform distribution" I would like you to read up on the Gibbs measure. It may not directly apply, but it is nice.

Comment: If you mean in measure, then your example totally works

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the limit of the function $f_n=\frac{1}{2n} \mathbb I_{[-n,n]}$