# How to assign shape to a distribution with infinite variance and "zero probability" for any finite measure of interval?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory

This was a revised question from [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3644064/603316) and based on an example provided by user779041.

It's been wildly known the mathematics of [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), which was thought not a function, but a distribution, that all the "probability distribution" went to a "point".([or as a generalization of the Gaussian distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196841/should-diracs-delta-function-be-regarded-as-a-subclass-of-the-gaussian-distribu))

$$p(x=0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{n}$$

However, consider the counterpart of such procedure, that the distribution was to spread out over the entire real axis, with infinite variance.

$$p(x|x\in(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}))=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}$$

Compare with the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), which also had infinite variance, one make further requirement that, at any finite measure of interval, the measure over the distribution was zero, i.e.

$$\int_{x\in[a,b]} dx p(x)=0$$

for some fixed $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.The procedure through limiting $\frac{1}{n}$ could make some sense, or equivalently taking the limit of $\sigma \rightarrow \infty$  in the Gaussian distribution.

However, unlike Dirac delta function, the new "reversed function"(say $\theta(x)$) was over an interval. With interval, there should be able to assign "shape"(say a "localized" function $s(x)$).

But how to assign such shape function to the $\theta(x)$, so that $\theta(x)$ could have "shape"/"weights" over the interval? How does the multiplication of two of such shaped $\theta(x)$ work?

*Extra point but not quite sure: the finite discontinuity in a shape function $s(x)$ might be ignored or smoothed out with the $\theta(x)$ if it works.

Comment: what means "finite measure of interval"? You mean that your probability distribution have the property that $P([a,b])=0$ for any chosen $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$? If this is the case, it is not possible, as $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{z\in \mathbb{Z}}[z,z+1]$ so $P(\mathbb{R})\leqslant \sum_{z\in \mathbb{Z}}P([z,z+1])=0\neq 1$

Comment: There can be no such distribution, since it would share the same interaction with test functions that the zero function does, and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 0=0$.

Comment: @Masacroso I guess then it's a number not in the real domain then. $\delta(0)\rightarrow \inf$ was also not real. Dirac delta was also not a function, but in terms of a distribution it made sense.